# Can't access WP functions in cron even though wp-load.php included

Tags: php, cron, wordpress

I have a file I have created to be run through a cron, but unfortunately, it can't seem to find some functions. `wp-load.php` is required, but when i try to access a few functions, including wp_create_category and wp_category_exists, I get back undefined for them. This is using the default wp-cron.php page, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Am I missing something about using crons with Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress functions from the default cron tab than the best way to achieve that is to use WordPress REST API.

Check out it's documentation [here](http://wp-api.org/).

Otherwise WordPress offers a way to implement cron jobs internally using `wp_cron();`, check out it's documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) :

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
  wp_mail( 'your@email.com', 'Automatic email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress.');
}
```

Comment: As they don't use a WP front end, the typical `wp_cron` functionality isn't an option. I'm gonna have to get approval to add a new plugin, and to see if it even works with our system (its a highly customized version of WP, a lot of plugins don't function properly on our setup).

Comment: @RhoVisions on a standard WordPress installation the REST API should do the trick, including WordPress core files is a really bad practice.

Comment: I know, I hate including files unless absolutely necessary (I've had to do it once or twice on custom code). Like I said, gotta run the new plugin up the chain.